# Can i gitignore Katalon Studio settings/internal folder?

Tags: gitignore, katalon-studio

When opening my project in Katalon Studio, the folder `settings/internals` refreshes, adding little to no new information (e.g. updating a comment with last open/modified data, see snipped), but making git think I have new stuff to commit.

Can I just put the entire folder in `.gitignore`? I had the `.gitignore` file created by Katalon Studio and the folder was not default-ignored. I don't want my collaborators to get crazy merging comment lines.

example `com.kms.katalon.composer.testcase.properties`

```
#Tue May 12 15:14:47 CEST 2020    <-- this lines gets updated when opening the project
testCaseTag=""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be the problem. You can safely gitignore the settings folder unless you wish your settings propagated to other team members.

There are a couple of discussions on the topic on the [Katalon](https://forum.katalon.com/t/gitignore-template-for-katalon-studio) [forum](https://forum.katalon.com/t/git-merge-conflict-com-kms-katalon-composer-testcase-properties).